# How to insert a new column before a specific column to a csv file in linux

Tags: linux

I just want to insert a new column to a csv file, here is an example:

The original test.csv file is like this:

```
A     B    C    D    E
V48   V53  V58  V15  V03
V39   V98  V13  V46  V56
```

Now, I want to insert F column before column C. How can I do this in linux?

```
A     B    F    C    D    E
V48   V53  V66  V58  V15  V03
V39   V98  V34  V13  V46  V56
```

Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `cut` and `paste`:

```bash
cut -f-2 original.csv | paste - new.csv <(cut -f3- original.csv)
```

- `cut` takes the first two columns
- pipes them to `paste`
- then `paste` combines the input from the first `cut`, the new column, and the remaining columns (again extracted with `cut`)

this assumes that the data in your files is delimited by tabs. If it was actually "comma-delimited", you'd have to add a `-d','` to all commands:

```bash
cut -f-2 -d',' original.csv | paste -d',' - new.csv <(cut -f3- -d',' original.csv)
```

Comment: Thank you @L_W for you solution, it really helped. But I ‘m a bit confused that I just want to add a new column with different strings, like add column F with V66 V34 to the original csv file. I just have one csv file. How can I do this?

Comment: No problem! How do you want to provide the new columns? As a string on the command line? In that case you can replace `new.csv` with `<(printf "header\n00\n01")`, i.e. print a string with newlines (`\n`) separating the rows and provided to paste with `<()`